# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в этом тексте?

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте уважаемая Мария! У меня возникли вопросы, касаемо КС "Данон" который будет проходить, а именно я хотел бы уточнить касаемо расходов , проезда и проживания, входит ли в расходы проезд Кемерово-Москва . Так же я хотел бы сказать что у меня есть перечень важных вопросов, касаемо нашего филиала и компании в целом.
Также хотел бы поблагодарить за тёплые слова, у на действительно произошла очень страшная трагедия, от которой мы очень скорбим всем городом.
С уважением председатель филиала " Молочный комбинат Кемеровский" АО " Данон России" Владилен .

Comment: А касаемо  - это что делаемо?

Comment: Уважаемый Владилен! Знаки препинания не самая главная проблема этого текста.

Comment: Что такое КС "Данон" и почему он в мужском роде?

Answer (score 1):

Уважаемый Владилен! Знаки препинания не самая главная проблема этого текста. Я постарался его исправить и улучшить. Вот что получилось.

Здравствуйте, уважаемая Мария!

В свази с предстоящим *заседанием/собранием/турниром/съездом* КС "Данон", я хотел бы уточнить, будут ли учтены расходы на проезд Кемерово — Москва. Также хотел бы сообщить, что у меня есть перечень важных вопросов (*вопросы не Ваши, у Вас только их перечень; если Вы хотите задать вопросы, то "у меня есть ряд важных вопросов"*), касающихся  нашего филиала и компании в целом. *(И что Мария должна с этой информацией делать?)* А также я хотел бы поблагодарить Вас за тёплые слова сочувствия и поддержки в связи с произошедшей у нас страшной трагедией, о жертвах которой мы очень скорбим всем городом.

С уважением,

Председатель Молочного комбината "Кемеровский" (филиала АО "Данон Россия") Владилен (Фамилия)

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, уважаемая Мария!

У меня возник вопрос по поводу предстоящего КС "Данон", а именно я хотел уточнить,  входит ли стоимость проезда Кемерово — Москва в общий перечень расходов на проезд и проживание. Также  хочу сообщить, что у меня есть ряд важных вопросов относительно нашего филиала и компании в целом.

Я хотел бы  поблагодарить Вас за тёплые слова поддержки, у нас действительно произошла  страшная трагедия, в связи с которой мы очень скорбим всем городом.

С уважением,

Председатель филиала "Молочный комбинат «Кемеровский» АО «Данон Россия»  Владилен

Comment: Про кавычки не знаю, я название из Интернета списала.

Comment: "Молочный комбинат «Кемеровский» пропали вторые кавычки

Comment: Из Википедии: Филиалы в России: 
«Молочный комбинат „Владимирский“»,
«Молочный комбинат „Волгоградский“»,
«Молочный комбинат „Кемеровский“»,

Comment: Я не уверена, что правильно в Википедии. Думаю, в названии автор разберется сам. Спасибо.

Comment: в связи в которой -> в связи с которой

Comment: Спасибо, исправлено.